# Dynamically add properties to the prototype object

Tags: javascript, api, dynamic, prototype

I was wondering the best way to dynamically add properties to the prototype object of a function (or if it's even a good idea).

This is what I came up with:

```
['foo', 'bar'].forEach(function(method) {
    String.prototype[method] = resolve;
});

function resolve() {
    // Who the hell called me?
}

'str'.foo();
```

I'm calling the same function `resolve()` for all the new properties I've added and I need to check who called the function (which property name) in order to figure an implementation based on that information.
It's all a matter of curiosity, I'm doing some tests on crazy JavaScript API implementations.

Do you guys have any suggestions for this?

Comment: For the ones wondering where did I used something like that, you can see it in action on this library I made: https://npmjs.org/package/unicorn

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
['foo', 'bar'].forEach(function (method) {
    String.prototype[method] = function () {
        resolve(method);
    };
});

function resolve(method) {
    alert(method);
}

("hello world").foo();
("hello world").bar();
```

Comment: Whoa, this was standing at my face and I didn't realized! Thank you @tracevipin!