# using a group of functions as a prototypes in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

We use like

```
String.prototype.EndsWith = function(){ ... }
```

What I'm trying to do is to have several functions and be able to add them to Number, String, ... or anything else, I'm trying to find a way that has a group of functions and I can just add one prototype to an object letting it access all of these functions

Comment: Have you tried using `Object.prototype`?

Comment: then it applies for everything? Number, String, Array, ...?

Comment: Subclass `String` with ES2015 class syntax: `class MyString extends String {/* your methods */}`. Never mutate built-in prototypes.

Comment: basically it's not completely clear what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863073/dynamically-add-properties-to-the-prototype-object**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863073/dynamically-add-properties-to-the-prototype-object) and some minor changes to suit my problem, this is it:

```
    var methods = {
        foo: function (x) { alert('foo:' + x); },
        bar: function(x){ alert('bar:'+x);}
    }
  for(var m in methods) String.prototype[m] = methods[m];

    "test".foo("aaaa");
    "test".bar("aaaa");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```js
String.prototype.myMethods = function(){
  var self = this; 
  return {
    endsWith: function(str){
      if (self.substr(str.length).localeCompare(str) === 0){
        return true; 
      }
      return false; 
    }, 
    beginsWith: function(str){
        if (self.substr(0,str.length).localeCompare(str) === 0){
          return true;  
        }
        return false; 
     }
  };
};

var str = "String"; 

console.log(str.myMethods().endsWith("ing"));
console.log(str.myMethods().endsWith("asdf"));
console.log(str.myMethods().beginsWith("Str"));
```